# How to get records which does not have entry in 2nd table

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

for ex

department

```
id  departmentname
1     x
2     y
3     z
```

employee

```
fkdepartmentid empname
         1      john
         1      sam
         2      ram
         3      hari
```

Here one `empname` can belong to any number of `department`s.

My requirement is get all the departments from `department` table where `empname!=john` (with a join).

I tried with the following query:

```
SELECT d.id FROM department d
 INNER JOIN employee e ON d.id=e.fkdepartmentid
  WHERE((e.empname<>'1')OR d.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT fkdepartmentid FROM employee WHERE fkdepartmentid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT fkdepartmentid FROM employee WHERE empname=sam)) ) GROUP BY d.id
```

However, the query is slow and failing in some scenarios.
the results should be 2 and 3. How can I achieve those results?

Comment: I think you may be asking the wrong question to the database. in the `employee` table there is a "non-john" employee for every department, so literally translating your requirement into an SQL query will return all departments *unless* a department contains nobody *but* john.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here you go

SELECT * FROM department WHERE id IN( SELECT fkdepartmentid FROM employee WHERE empname !='john' GROUP BY fkdepartmentid )
```

Comment: I think you may be asking the wrong question to the database. in the `employee` table there is a "non-john" employee for every department, so literally translating your requirement into an SQL query will return all departments *unless* a department contains nobody *but* john.

Comment: See his question he is asking for exactly `empname!=john` not with occurrence in name

Comment: Whoops. I meant to post that as a comment to the question, not your answer. Sorry. :)

Comment: @JanKrüger it happens sometime buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly you want to exclude department 1 because Jhon is an employer of that department. If it so you need to reverse the conditions.

Try

```
SELECT * 
  FROM department
 WHERE id NOT IN
( 
  SELECT fkdepartmentid 
    FROM employee 
   WHERE empname = 'john' 
   GROUP BY fkdepartmentid
)
```

Output:

```
| ID | DEPARTMENTNAME |
-----------------------
|  2 |              y |
|  3 |              z |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfa407/8)** demo

Answer (score 0):

here is one which does not use nested queries:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM department AS t1
LEFT JOIN employee AS t2
ON t2.deptid = t1.id AND t2.name IN ('john', 'rari')
WHERE t2.name IS NULL;
```

this lists all departments which does not have any employee with the name in list.

Comment: Hi ,this query is working when there is one value.but if i want to get departments which doesn't have employees john and ram its not working as expected.INSERT INTO employee (fkdepartmentid, empname)
VALUES
(1, 'john'),
(1, 'sam'),
(1, 'med'),
(2, 'ram'),
(2, 'ram6'),
(3, 'rari'),
(4, 'john'),
(4, 'raqm8'); for this i tried    select * from
department AS t1
left join employee AS t2 on t2.fkdepartmentid = t1.id and (t2.empname = 'sam' or t2.empname = 'ram')
where t2.fkdepartmentid is null. don't mind please help me out.